# Percentage appears in the graphical view of summary response in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Percentage appears in the graphical view of summary response for a rating scale question in SharePoint 2010 after adding all percentage values it's  101 percentage? what is the possible cause for that...and how to fix this. please help

[image]